# How to group and order with multiple tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

How do I group by a column and order by frequency if I am getting the column from multiple tables? For example, I have 3 tables, Table_A, Table_B, Table_C. Each of them has a column of the same data. 
e.g Table_A

```
col
------
aaa
bbb
aaa
ccc
```

e.g Table_B

```
aaa
ccc
ddd
bbb
```

and likewise similar data for Table_C. I want to have the following as the result:

```
aaa 3
bbb 2
ccc 2
ddd 1
```

Currently, I have this

```
select col, count(*) from Table_A UNION select col, count(*) from Table_B UNION select col, count(*) from Table_C group by col order by count(*) desc
```

But this does not give me the results I wanted. thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
select      col
           ,count(*) as cnt

from        (         select col from Table_A
            union all select col from Table_B
            union all select col from Table_C
            ) t

group by    col

order by    cnt desc
           ,col
;
```

OR

```
select      col
           ,sum(cnt) as sum_cnt

from        (         select col,count(*) as cnt from Table_A group by col
            union all select col,count(*)        from Table_B group by col
            union all select col,count(*)        from Table_C group by col
            ) 

group by    col

order by    sum_cnt desc
           ,col
;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use `union all`, then do the aggregation.  The correct syntax is:

```
select col, count(*) as cnt
from (select col from Table_A
      union all
      select col from Table_B
      union all
      select col from Table_C         
     ) abc
group by col 
order by col;
```

You can also pre-aggregate the data, but you need to aggregate again:

```
select col, sum(cnt) as sum_cnt
from (select col, count(*) as cnt from Table_A group by col
      union all
      select col, count(*) from Table_B group by col
      union all
      select col, count(*) from Table_C group by col
     ) abc
group by col
order by col;
```

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz . . . I describe how I indent my code in Chapter 1 of *Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel*.  Please don't do me any favors by changing how I write the code.  I appreciate any small changes that are made, but resent changes to the indenting style.

Comment: I wouldn't change for a style. 1st change was for ORDER BY. 2nd change was because the code was invalid due to brackets mismatch, when all brackets where actually redundant. I also wrote my own answer which is basically the same code (but working...) but I deleted it after a minute since I didn't want to steal a correct answer under your nose.

Comment: This is not valid SQL: `Error: near "union": syntax error`

Comment: Apparently `(select col from Table_A) union all (select col from Table_B)` is not valid for SQLite but is valid for Teradata, Oracle, SQL Server, PostgreSQL and MySQL.

Answer (score -1):

Each select needs its own group by-clause.

select col, count(*)
from Table_A 
group by col
UNION 
select col, count(*) 
from Table_B
group by col 
UNION 
select col, count(*) 
from Table_C 
group by col 
order by 2 desc;

Comment: Down-voted. Wrong logic and misuse of set operators.